# Python3 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dotenv'

Tags: python, python-3.x, dotenv, python-dotenv

I'm getting `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dotenv'` error. I did install `python-dotenv` as suggested in other posts but it still gives error. How to fix it?

**My code**

```
import os
import json

import openai
import pandas as pd

from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()
...
```

**Error**

```
(.venv) ~/ROOT/Python/finetunechat/openai $ pip list | grep dotenv
    python-dotenv 0.21.1
    (.venv) ~/ROOT/Python/finetunechat/openai $ python 1.py
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "1.py", line 7, in <module>
        from dotenv import load_dotenv
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dotenv'
    (.venv) ~/ROOT/Python/finetunechat/openai $
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Make sure it's installed in the same virtual environment (venv) as your project

```
pip install python-dotenv
```

Before running that command ensure your venv is live by running:

For Mac/Linux

```
source .venv/bin/activate
```

For Windows

```
.venv\Scripts\activate
```

Also try reopening the project after installing

Hope this helps!